# Is there a performance issue if I dispatch an Event every frame in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, performance

Basically all I want to know is if there will be a hit on performance as I dispatch events more frequently, or if this is a trivial task for flash to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And no. Every time Flash dispatchs a message, it creates an Event object. Be it on ENTER_FRAME or MOUSE_MOVE or whatever event. That will consume memory, but that is until it is collected by the garbage collector. I invite you to read a question I made a few years ago, because the answer I got applies to your question.

[Why Sytem.totalMemory keeps increasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020146/why-sytem-totalmemory-keeps-increasing)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the answer on the question you asked answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hard to answer. You can fire events as often as you want. Performance issues, you are creating in the code of the handlers for theses events.

Comment: Assume that no listeners have been created to listen for these events - I just want to know if the actual dispatching on its own is performance hindering.

Comment: Can't imagine that. Where do you want to fire so much events that you event think about it?

Comment: It's more of a theoretical question and based on the results I'll be modifying a framework of mine.

Comment: Whenever I would personally worry of having too many ENTER_FRAME events fired on each frames, I would have a singleton "Updater" class dedicated to listen for the ENTER_FRAME event and have all classes that requires looping to subscribe (append their callback methods) to this Updater class. It's also easier to keep a count of all subscribers and remove them all at once if need be.

Comment: Right you are, this is a strategy I have used for a long time now. Though ENTER_FRAME is still being dispatched by each object whether you listen for it or not, right?